# Avoiding to defer "child" object construction with `operator<<`

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, variadic-templates, c++14

Let's say I have a container object that stores an `std::vector` of polymorphic children.

```
struct Child
{
    Child(Parent& mParent) { /* ... */ }
    virtual ~Child() { }
};

class Parent
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> children;

        template<typename T, typename... TArgs> 
        auto& mkChild(TArgs&&... mArgs)
        {
            // `static_assert` that `T` is derived from `Child`...
            children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...));
            return *children.back();
        }

    public:
        template<typename T, typename... TArgs> 
        auto& add(TArgs&&... mArgs)
        {
            mkChild<T>(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...));
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Now I can use the `Parent` class like this:

```
int main()
{
    Parent p;
    p.add<Child1>(some_args1).add<Child2>(some_args2);
}
```

While this syntax achieves what I want to do (chaining addition of children to a single parent), I find it very hard to read, especially in my real use case.

I would really like to use `operator<<` instead. But I cannot figure out a way to construct the children in place.

```
// Desired syntax
int main()
{
    Parent p;
    p << mk<Child1>(some_args1) << mk<Child2>(some_args2);
}
```

Notice how I never specify the parent in the `mk` function.

I do not want to say `mk<Child1>(p, some_args1)`. The compiler should figure out `p` from the chaining of `operator<<`.

**Is there any way I can implement this `mk` function generating code equal to the one generated via the `.add<T>(...)` chaining?**

The only way I managed to implement this is using a *man-in-the-middle* struct that holds the construction variadic parameters for the child class.

```
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> struct DeferCtor
{
    std::tuple<TArgs...> ctorArgs;
};
```

Then `operator<<(DeferCtor<T, TArgs...>&)` would deal with the object's construction inside `Parent`.

**Is there a way to avoid this step, while still having the desired syntax? (Not passing the parent instance in the `mk` function.)**

Comment: Can't mk be the class rather than the function (with a template constructor or make entire class to be a template)?

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: The point is that the children are all classes in the same polymorphic inheritance, and they also all take a reference to the parent as the first constructor parameter. Hiding these details behind a variadic template `mk` functions makes the code less-error prone, more readable, and allows the user not to explicitly create an `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Mhm, I see, so basically you want to pass the value of p to the mk function without literally passing it to the function. Very interesting problem...

Comment: I undersand it's interesting but what is the benefit of doing this instead of just taking unique_ptr to base class of already contructed objects? Can you give a full example of the desired syntax?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: readibility, easeness of use. Look at this example I've just written: http://pastebin.com/X1pah700

I find the `unique_ptr` version hard to read, the `add()` is ok, but the one I prefer is the stream-like version that uses `mk()`.

Comment: What I mean is, that you can do 
`p << mk<Child1>(some_args1) << mk<Child2>(some_args2);`
if you just let `mk` be `make_unique`, and let `p.operator << ` take a `uniqe_ptr` to base class

Comment: What if you pass the child type as kind of stream formatter and then pass the arguments lets say like this: `p << mk<Child> << some_args;` would it be acceptable for you?

Comment: Your *man-in-the-middle* looks a lot like expression templates. It should be possible to store references to the arguments instead of the arguments itself.

Comment: Have you considered Sean Parent's approach of enclosing the passed object in an inheritance hierarchy internally? I.e. you pass some arbitrary type fulfilling a *concept* rather than being derived from a common base class, then internally in `add`, wrap it into some type deriving from a private nested base class.

Comment: Binary operators have, well, only two operands. And your object construction potentially has N operands for the object to be constructed, plus one target (parent). You could, for example, chain postfix-expressions instead, e.g. function calls (à la boost initialization): `p.add()(tag_v<Child1>, a, b)(tag_v<Child2>, a, b)`. Though that probably doesn't improve readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't really making objects in place in your existing code -- you're making the child objects on the heap with a `unique_ptr` and then *moving* that `unique_ptr` into parent.  You can do the same with your `operator<<` if you just define it as taking a `unique_ptr`:

```
Parent &Parent::operator<<(std::unique_ptr<Child> ch) {
    children.emplace_back(std::move(ch)); }
```

Now assuming your `mk` global function is essentially just an alias for `make_unique`:

```
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> 
std::unique_ptr<T> mk(TArgs&&... mArgs) {
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...)); }
```

you should be able to use your desired syntax.

Answer (score 1):

(based on my previous comments). I suggest you construct the unique_ptr of base and feed that to `opertor<<` [(ideone link)](http://ideone.com/a62PKO). No need to get fancy or complicated.

```
using namespace std;
using mk = make_unique; 

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class B {};
class D : public B {};
class E : public B {};

class A {
public:
    A & operator << ( std::unique_ptr<B> bp){
        std::cout << " added a value " << std::endl;
        // children.push_back(move(bp));
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    A a;
    a << mk<D>( .. some argument ) <<  mk<E>( other arguments) ;
}
```